# How to send modal attribute to a redirected page in spring mvc

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

JAVA:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(ModelMap model, HttpSession session, 
        @RequestParam("userID") String userID) {

    try {
        model.addAttribute("userID", userID);

        String redirectUrl = "http://localhost:8081/app/home.htm";
        return "redirect:" + redirectUrl;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

JSP:

```
<div class="position-relative">
    <h1>
        ${userID}
    </h1>
</div>
```

Here when it is redirected to the home page, the modal attributes are appended as URL parameters. But what I need it as an attribute in home page. How is it possible? Or is there a way to pass data to a redirected page without appending it as a URL parameter.

Please suggest a method.

Comment: Add `RedirectAttributes` as an argument to your method and instead of putting the `userId` into the model put it as flash attributes in the `RedirectAttribute` object.

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/spring-mvc-flash-attributes.html for FlashScope example